# Why the Failure message is duplicated inside the step also in the html report

Tags: allure

I have an allure xml something like below

```
<test-case start="1456329345978" stop="1456329352078" status="failed">
<name>SYSTEM_ASSERT_ERRORS</name>
<title>Assert that there are no critical errors</title>
<description type="text">Assert that there are no critical errors </description>
<failure>
    <message>AssertionError: FAIL: 3 out of 4 test steps failed</message>
    <stack-trace>java.lang.AssertionError: FAIL: 3 out of 4 test steps failed: Not true that &lt;3&gt; is equal to &lt;0&gt;        
    </stack-trace>
</failure>
<steps>                
    <step start="1456329346636" stop="1456329351963" status="passed">
        <name>verifyLogs[JSchException]</name>
        <title>verifyLogs: [JSchException]</title>                    
    </step>
    <step start="1456329346636" stop="1456329351965" status="failed">
        <name>verifyLogs["Error code"]</name>
        <title>verifyLogs: ["Error code"]</title>                    
    </step>                
</steps>
<attachments>
    <attachment title="log.txt" source="1be56864-2031-4e82-bfdd-ce5152a5bbc2-attachment.txt" type="text/plain"/>
</attachments>
```

On converting this to html,
Failure is shown at the top of the test case pane and also just below the first failed step?

I don't see a reason for displaying it again in there? Any reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be to make failed test step visible. Also, if you have many test steps you can check the stack trace of failed step without scrolling in the very top.

If you catch exceptions inside your test or map them, real exception thrown by test step could be different from one reported by Allure. It is considered bad practice (as well as managing threads inside your test) and is not supported by Allure, AFAIK.

So, I don't see an issue here for now.

Comment: Assuming multiple test steps failed..stack trace of which one will be shown at the top.

Comment: Multiple test steps failure assumes you try-catch exceptions inside your test, which is considered a bad practice. At the top exception will be shown - one thrown by test method (which can't be multiple).

Comment: test steps are treated like a soft assert here...not sure on the bad practice here...